# Disable sorting in crosstab birt

Tags: report, birt

is there a simple way to disable the default sorting in birt cross-tab.

Answer (score 0):

add dummy Group(Dimension) and add it to the design as a hidden column. The cross-tab will sort according to the hidden column.